# How to upload file and get progressbar using axios in react js with header authorization

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios, authorization, progress-bar

I want to make an upload form with a progress bar in react js using axios

```
const option = {
            onUploadProgress : (ProgressEvent) => {
                const {loaded, total} = ProgressEvent;
                let percent = Math.floor(loaded * 100 / total)
                console.log('tes get value for progress upload : ',`${loaded} kb of ${total} kb | ${percent}%`)
            }
        }

        let res = await InsertData(param, option)
```

Api services (successfully insert data, but haven't got value for upload progress )

```
export const InsertData = async (req, opt) => {
const url = `${appConfig.BASE_API}/insert`;
let cookie=cookies.get('user')
createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axios, refreshAuthLogic);  
const result=await axios.post(url,req,
  {headers : {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' :'Bearer '+ cookie.token
  }}
  )
.then(res=>{
  return res.data
  })    
 .catch (error=> {
  return null;
})
return result};
```

then i try :
(got a value for upload progress, but failed to insert data due to error 401 Unauthorized. It seems because the auth header is unreadable. Considering axios.post only sends 3 parameters )

```
export const InsertDS = async (req, opt) => {
const url = `${appConfig.BASE_API}/insert`;
let cookie=cookies.get('user')
createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axios, refreshAuthLogic);  
const result=await axios.post(url,req, opt,
  {headers : {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' :'Bearer '+ cookie.token
  }}
  )
.then(res=>{
  return res.data
  })    
 .catch (error=> {
  return null;
})
return result};
```

[Please click this link image to see console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TXQa.png)

how do I get the value for the upload progress and don't get a 401 error Unauthorized ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution you just need to add the progress bar detail beside the header request like this cod :

```
axios
      .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/video/add/${id}`, fData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
        },
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
          let percent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
          setUpload(`${loaded}kb of ${total}kb | ${percent}%`);
        },
      })
```